# Unable to define object with init and children

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm defining the following object which I intend to use to mock Mongoose models during Mocha tests. I'm writing it in Coffeescript, therefore I have no access to the `function` keyword:

```
TodoError = (body) ->
  @find = (query, callback) ->
    callback 'error', false
  @save = (query, callback) ->
    callback 'error', false
  @init = (body) -> {}
  @init body
  return @
```

This object is getting called in the following ways:

```
TodoError.find {}, (error, todos) -> {}
```

and

```
todo = new TodoError body
todo.save (error, todo) -> {}
```

This results in the following error when I try and call `TodoError.find`

```
TypeError: Object function (body) {
  this.find = function(query, callback) {
    return callback('error', false);
  };
  this.save = function(query, callback) {
    return callback('error', false);
  };
  this.init = function(body) {
    return {};
  };
  this.init(body);
  return this;
} has no method 'find'
```

I originally had this working for `TodoError.find` with the following definition however I realised this wouldn't work when I come to the `new TodoError` part:

```
  TodoError =
    find : (query, callback) ->
      callback 'error', false
    save : (query, callback) ->
      callback 'error', false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I had totally forgotten all about `prototype` and then finally found my way to Coffeescript classes, with this solution

```
class TodoError
  # constructor doesn't need to do anything.
  constructor: (body) ->

  #static methods.
  @find: (query, callback) ->
    callback 'error', false
  @findOne: (query, callback) ->
    callback 'error', false

  #instance methods.
  save: (callback) ->
    callback 'error', false
```

This compiles to:

```
TodoError = (function() {
  function TodoError(body) {}

  TodoError.find = function(query, callback) {
    return callback('error', false);
  };

  TodoError.findOne = function(query, callback) {
    return callback('error', false);
  };

  TodoError.prototype.save = function(callback) {
    return callback('error', false);
  };

  return TodoError;

})();
```